# DialogFlow Manual Handover to Facebook Messenger

Tags: dialogflow-es, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I've successfully setup a DialogFlow bot which integrates with Facebook Messenger.

Is it possible for a human user to log into the Facebook Messenger inbox and take manual control over the conversation?

When I log into the Facebook Messenger inbox I've been unable to stop the bot from replying to the user and as a result it ends up being a 3 way conversation between me, the user and the bot.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, how are you populating the bot responses, are you using fulfilment (Webhooks)?

Comment: Thanks @BcfAnt, presently I have configured Facebook responses in the Response section of my intents.

Answer (score 1):

This usecases makes sense but is not well documented. Facebook mentions this in the [handover protocol documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/handover-protocol/):

**Taking Thread Control From Facebook Page Inbox**
*For Messenger experiences that enable live chat via Facebook Page Inbox, the handover protocol allows the Page admin to manually initiate a take thread control event by moving the conversation from 'Done' to the 'Inbox'. It is important to note that the thread would immediately be passed to Facebook Page Inbox irrespective of the current app’s role.*

I guess this is what you need.

What you need to do is this:

1. Find the conversation you want to manual control
2. Check 'Move to Done'
3. FInd the conversation again by adding the 'done'-filter
4. Click the Move to Main button (the envelop in the top right
   corner)
5. Remove the 'done' filter to find the conversation

from now on, the inbox has control and your chatbot will not respond if the user types a message. You will be the only one responding

If you need the chatbot to manage the conversation again, just click on the Move to Done-checkmark and the chatbot has control again.

Ps: the documentation also suggests you to subscribe to two webhooks (Standby and messaging-handovers). To be honest: for me it worked with and without subscribing to these webhooks